# Membership / Authorization over a REST service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, security, rest

I'm investigating creating a WCF REST service for an existing asp.net application to be consumed by various clients including Windows Phone 7, Android, iPhone apps etc.

Creating a simple WCF REST service and consuming it from the above platforms is not a problem and works really well.  What I am struggling to get my head around is authorization.

The asp.net application uses the Membership provider to provide authentication and authorization and I'm comfortable in using that API from the REST service.

How do I secure my REST service so that the first call has to be to authenticate (passing the username and password) and following calls know who is 'logged in'.  I'm guessing the authenticate method will have to pass back some sort of token to be used in subsequent calls identifying the caller.  Is this secure enough as the whole site / service is over SSL?

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the token approach is better then just sending username+password (Basic Authentication) in each request. The problem is to implement it correctly: while Basic Authentication is very easy to implement, and actually it's already implemented by most application and web servers, the token is something you'll need to implement yourself - it must be encrypted, so clients won't understand it, so you'll need some keys management, it also must have some expiration date and may be you'll want some revoke functionality.
In addition, it will make client's life harder: instead of just attaching basic authentication header to each request, client must first go to some authentication point, receive a valid taken and then use the token on the requests. If the token expires, the client will need to go to the authentication point again.

So if you have time and knowledge, and your clients are smart, it's better to use the token approach. Otherwise with SSL, basic authentication should be sufficient.

Comment: I think I prefer the token approach than sending the username and password on each request. I understand it's not strictly RESTful as I will have to maintain state, but in this instance I'm happy to live with that.

Comment: I can't see why you say that the token (i.e. session ID in cookie if I understand you) is better. It makes your application statefull, which is absolutely not restful, make life harder for client, is not more secure (cf. session hijacking), make life harder for server (load balancing is far harder in a statefull app)... can you elaborate why you think it's better ?

Comment: Actually I didn't mean to put the session id in a cookie, but rather some encrypted token in a header. This doesn't change the stateless nature of REST. It's better since you don't need to send password on each request, so it reduces the possibility that the password would be stolen. It's also allows SSO scenarios: user has logged-in into an application that needs to invoke the REST call, so the application uses the encrypted token instead of password. Actually the password is never used after the login.

Comment: Btw, using any sort of a cookie authentication with REST makes it vulnerable to the CSRF attacks. But using a propriety header does not have this weakness.

Comment: I aggree with the SSO aspect, but in other cases, if you use SSL or Digest Auth, the password can't be stollen, so there is no use for an obscure token.  Moreover, if you use a custom header, you are bound to a custom client. About the CSRF, I agree, that's why I suggested HTTPAuth instead of cookie, but CSRF is not a problem if you use a custom client (i.e. rich client with pure xml/json data exchange). Appart for SSO consideration, I would use HTTP Auth (and even in this case, WebID is your friend ;)

Comment: Again: I don't tell that using BA over SSL or Digest is bad. I only say that IMO using token, if you use it correctly, is better. The main reason: it's not a good practice if the client needs to hold password and send it over and over again, since it increases the chances that password will be stolen: in this way or in another. That's all. You say it's impossible to hack SSO, and this is true, but actually only partially. Here comes the recent example: http://www.comodo.com/Comodo-Fraud-Incident-2011-03-23.html

Answer (score 4):

The more restful authentication scheme is to use HTTP Authentication, e.g. Basic or Digest. Since your service is over SSL, Basic should be sufficient. The authentification tokens (login/password) are sent with every request, so that the service can be stateless. Every client library that I'm aware of can deal with basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen an example in the latest Windows Azure toolkit for WP7 that might be helpful for you. It basically uses the Membership Provider, logs in a person (the first time the person installs the app) and then generates a Ticket. It then Encrypts this ticket and sends it back as a TOKEN which is then stored on the phone in the isolated storage. The expiration of the ticket is set to int.MaxValue so that the token remains good for a long period of time.

Now, this token is passed over to the Web Services in the Authorization Header where it is decrypted, the identity of the user is verified and then the web service call is made.

Hoping this helps. I am trying to solve a similar scenario and trust me, there isn't much out there that points us in the right direction...which is a pretty sad state of affairs if you ask me.